# creating subsection or separate section in a table using angular

Tags: angularjs

[image]

I would like to show my model in separate sections or as a subsection in a table. For e.g., Newyork table will show all Newyork data and Florida table will show all Florida data. I have a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/jGtZOAx0mqKDx0MW7p2g?p=preview) which describes on how I achieved it. I have also given it below, just in case plunker gets edited in the future. I would like to know if it could be done dynamically. I mean, if the number of states are higher, I will end up adding more and more html tables. Please help.

```
//scripts.js
var module = angular.module("app", []);

var appCtrl = [
  "$scope",
  function($scope){
    $scope.trackingType = "Unverified Offsets By States";

    $scope.exists = function(val) {
            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.unVerifiedOffsets.length; i++) {
                if ($scope.unVerifiedOffsets[i].sortKey === val) {
                    console.log('Loop is going to break.');
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        };

    $scope.unVerifiedOffsets = [{
      "offset_Id": 1997153,
      "amount": -3375987.81,
      "sortKey": 3
    }, {
      "offset_Id": 1995696,
      "amount": -1000,
      "sortKey": 3
    }, {
      "offset_Id": 1997148,
      "amount": -30,
      "sortKey": 3
    }, {
      "offset_Id": 1997154,
      "amount": -10.06,
      "sortKey": 3
    }, {
      "offset_Id": 1996360,
      "amount": 2.15,
      "sortKey": 3
    }, {
      "offset_Id": 1997145,
      "amount": 75,
      "sortKey": 3
    }, {
      "offset_Id": 1997143,
      "amount": 200,
      "sortKey": 3
    }, {
      "offset_Id": 1997146,
      "amount": 200,
      "sortKey": 3
    }, {
      "offset_Id": 1997144,
      "amount": 200,
      "sortKey": 3
    }, {
      "offset_Id": 1997141,
      "amount": 700,
      "sortKey": 3
    }, {
      "offset_Id": 1997147,
      "amount": 1793.24,
      "sortKey": 3
    }, {
      "offset_Id": 1997152,
      "amount": 41885.8,
      "sortKey": 3
    }, {
      "offset_Id": 1997151,
      "amount": 90081.62,
      "sortKey": 3
    }, {
      "offset_Id": 1997142,
      "amount": 144634.81,
      "sortKey": 3
    }, {
      "offset_Id": 1997150,
      "amount": 336146,
      "sortKey": 3
    }, {
      "offset_Id": 1997157,
      "amount": 0,
      "sortKey": 4
    }];
  }];

module.controller("appCtrl",  appCtrl);


//index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.4" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    <link data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.3.6" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@*" data-semver="3.3.6" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <script data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.3.6" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.2.1" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.1/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="appCtrl">
    <h3>{{ trackingType }}</h3>
    <div data-ng-show="unVerifiedOffsets && unVerifiedOffsets.length > 0 && exists(1)">
        <h4 class="span12">Texas</h4>
        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Amount</th>
                <th>Sort Key</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr data-ng-repeat="uvo in unVerifiedOffsets | filter: { sortKey : 1 }">
                <td>
                  <input type="checkbox" value="{{ uvo.offset_Id }}" />
                </td>
                <td>{{ uvo.amount | currency }}</td>
                <td>{{ uvo.sortKey }}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>

    <div data-ng-show="unVerifiedOffsets && unVerifiedOffsets.length > 0 && exists(2)">
        <h4 class="span12">California</h4>
        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Amount</th>
                <th>Sort Key</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr data-ng-repeat="uvo in unVerifiedOffsets | filter: { sortKey : 2 }">
                <td>
                  <input type="checkbox" value="{{ uvo.offset_Id }}" />
                </td>
                <td>{{ uvo.amount | currency }}</td>
                <td>{{ uvo.sortKey }}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>

    <div data-ng-show="unVerifiedOffsets && unVerifiedOffsets.length > 0 && exists(3)">
        <h4 class="span12">New york</h4>
        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Amount</th>
                <th>Sort Key</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr data-ng-repeat="uvo in unVerifiedOffsets | filter: { sortKey : 3 }">
                <td>
                  <input type="checkbox" value="{{ uvo.offset_Id }}" />
                </td>
                <td>{{ uvo.amount | currency }}</td>
                <td>{{ uvo.sortKey }}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>

    <div data-ng-show="unVerifiedOffsets && unVerifiedOffsets.length > 0 && exists(4)">
        <h4 class="span12">Florida</h4>
        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Amount</th>
                <th>Sort Key</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr data-ng-repeat="uvo in unVerifiedOffsets | filter: { sortKey : 4 }">
                <td>
                  <input type="checkbox" value="{{ uvo.offset_Id }}" />
                </td>
                <td>{{ uvo.amount | currency }}</td>
                <td>{{ uvo.sortKey }}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a simple directive to consolidate the html template and then simply pass in the variables that change.

here is a Plunker showing it:

http://plnkr.co/edit/PIwj2TkF2d8RGHXNnOe7?p=preview

This would be an example of the html directive:

```
<statetable ng-repeat="state in states" stateName="{{state.stateName}}" existsNumber="{{state.existsNumber}}" sortKey="{{state.sortKey}}"></statetable>
```

Here is the directive code:

```
module.directive("statetable",function(){

  var directive = {
restrict: "EA",
replace: true,
template:[
  '<div data-ng-show="unVerifiedOffsets && unVerifiedOffsets.length > 0 && exists(existsnumber)">',
    '<h4 class="span12">{{statename}}</h4>',
    '<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">',
        '<thead>',
          '<tr>',
            '<th></th>',
            '<th>Amount</th>',
            '<th>Sort Key</th>',
          '</tr>',
        '</thead>',
        '<tbody>',
          '<tr data-ng-repeat="uvo in unVerifiedOffsets | filter: { sortKey : sortkey }">',
            '<td>',
              '<input type="checkbox" value="{{ uvo.offset_Id }}" />',
            '</td>',
            '<td>{{ uvo.amount | currency }}</td>',
            '<td>{{ uvo.sortKey }}</td>',
          '</tr>',
        '</tbody>',
  '</table>',
'</div>',
  ].join(''),
link:function(scope, element, attrs){
  scope.statename = attrs.statename;
  scope.existsnumber = attrs.existsnumber*1;
  scope.sortkey = attrs.sortkey;
},
 };
 return directive;
});
```

and then you would need the state name/key array in your controller:

```
$scope.states = [{
      stateName: "Texas",
      existsNumber: "1",
      sortKey: "1"
    },
    {
      stateName: "California",
      existsNumber: "2",
      sortKey: "2"
    },
    {
      stateName: "New york",
      existsNumber: "3",
      sortKey: "3"
    },
    {
      stateName:"Florida",
      existsNumber: "4",
      sortKey: "4"
    }]
```

now you can just add to the states array with the proper codes and it'll work

Comment: your answer helped me. Particularly, the $scope.states. I did not even think about looping it through the distinct states. Thanks for the helps. I did not want to use your directive as it would make this simple page more complex.

Answer (score 0):

Kyle's answer helped me. So I am going to accept his answer because there might be people who would be looking for template and derivatives.

But I did not want to use a directive. I updated my [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/jGtZOAx0mqKDx0MW7p2g?p=preview) and below is how I did it.

I added the list of states as Kyle suggested to my scope [which basically comes from the database].

```
$scope.availableOffsets = [{
      stateName: "Texas",
      sortKey: "1"
    }, {
      stateName: "California",
      sortKey: "2"
    }, {
      stateName: "New york",
      sortKey: "3"
    }, {
      stateName: "Florida",
      sortKey: "4"
    }]
```

Then I updated my html file as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.4" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  <link data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.3.6" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />
  <link data-require="bootstrap-css@*" data-semver="3.3.6" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />
  <script data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.3.6" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.2.1" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.1/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="appCtrl">
  <h3>{{ trackingType }}</h3>
  <div data-ng-repeat="avo in availableOffsets" data-ng-show="unVerifiedOffsets && unVerifiedOffsets.length > 0">
    <div data-ng-show="exists(avo.sortKey)">
      <h4 class="span12">{{ avo.stateName }}</h4>
      <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Amount</th>
            <th>Sort Key</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr data-ng-repeat="uvo in unVerifiedOffsets | filter: { sortKey : avo.sortKey }">
            <td>
              <input type="checkbox" value="{{ uvo.offset_Id }}" />
            </td>
            <td>{{ uvo.amount | currency }}</td>
            <td>{{ uvo.sortKey }}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

That did the trick. Note the div which is used to wrap up the earlier div.